# Create Folder using Jam

Tags: jam

I'm using jam in my project to automate building in Visual Studio.

I'm trying to move subdirectories and files from $folder to $folder1.
$folder is containing a project
$folder1 is empty.

I use File to copy files.

I try to copy files like this:

```
File ($folder1) : ($folder) ; //works

File ($folder1)\\subdir : ($folder)\\subdir //don't work

//etc...
```

But $folder1 is empty and does not contain a folder structure so File `($folder1)\\subdir : ($folder)\\subdir` doesn't do anything because $folder1 is empty.

Is there way in Jam to create a folder depending if it exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `MkDir`

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/view/guest/perforce_software/jam/src/Jambase.html

It's important that you add the `target` as a `Depends`

```
Depends rule : $(1) ;

MkDir $(1) ;
```